# golang experimentation at runtime

Tags: go

Often when I'm coding I like to see how things work or what certain expressions yield at a specific area in my code base.

Most other languages provide tools to evaluate new custom expressions at runtime.  Golang doesn't seem to provide this yet, or at least with the tools I've used  (sublime, goclipse).

Currently I'm solving this by using Println or recreating a small test environment that sets up just what I need to run some on the fly expressions, but I'm figuring there must be a better way...

I could use something like play.golang.org, but often I have a lot of dependencies or it would require a lot of copy and pasting to make my simple trial-and-error code work.

Comment: What's wrong with just having a scratch file open in your editor, and using `go run`?  I'll usually have play file open in vim, and in the terminal I just repeat the last `go run play.go` command.

Comment: I dont get context with a scratch file. I have to manually recreate it which is often cumbersome

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably you are looking for a debugger (to insert breakpoints, stop at them and start playing with variables there).

One of the debuggers is https://github.com/mailgun/godebug and you can read more how to use it in this [blogpost](https://blog.cloudflare.com/go-has-a-debugger-and-its-awesome/).

Comment: Actually, this will work.  I'm looking for the 'p' in godebug.  The default debugger in goclipse is gdb and I thought it was the only one that people use.  I'm new to go, so I didn't know there were alternatives.

Comment: p(rint) [expression] print a variable or any other Go expression

Answer (score 1):

Have you already tried https://github.com/motemen/gore project?

Comment: I actually have not.  I'm brand new to go and hadn't heard of it until now.  But if I want to evaluate an expression in the context of a function call, it seems like this would be extremely difficult using gore

Answer (score 0):

Sublime and VIM now support the go plugin but the usage is a little esoteric.

The JetBrains IdeaJ community IDE with the go debug plugin has worked really, really well for me.  That said, starting out, the value of a quick `go run` with `fmt.Println` can't be overstated.

Comment: Yeah, I can get most of this functionality with goclipse as well, but watch expressions dont work which is what I'm really looking for